# Magento 2 and BrainTree - Phone Number

Tags: magento2, braintree

I was getting an error while trying to process credit cards through BrainTree.  The error was was getting back was:

[VALIDATION ERRORS] 92201 (Company name/DBA section must be either 3, 7 or 12 characters and the product descriptor can be up to 18, 14, or 9 characters respectively (with an * in between for a total descriptor name of 22 characters).), 92202 (Phone must contain exactly 10 digits, and can only contain numbers, dashes, parentheses and periods.) [MERCHANT: pzr9p32sxcpck4mv]",

[VALIDATION ERRORS] \"(779) 601-0340\" failed to match phone regex

I take this error as the phone number must be digits only.  But Magento formats the number and/or allows all characters.  Is there anyway to change the phone number to only and max 10 digits?

Or someone else have an idea how to get around this BrainTree error?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The dynamic descriptors section can be empty as they are optional. If left empty, the descriptor that appears on your customers' statements will be what's known as the [hard descriptor](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/descriptors).

Answer (score 0):

The problem for us was not with the Customer Phone number but the company phone number as specified by the **Dynamic Descriptors**. It does need to be exactly 10 digits. Go to Magento 2 Admin > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Default Config > Braintree Configure > Dynamic Descriptors.

[image: Dynamic Desciptor]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dynamic descriptors solved this issue for me
in Magento>Braintree config
I could not get it to work at all with any values. Kept getting the

> Payment Error: 92201 [] []
> [2021-07-21 21:36:06] main.CRITICAL: Payment Error: Company name/DBA section must be either 3, 7 or 12 characters and the product descriptor can be up to 18, 14, or 9 characters respectively (with an * in between for a total descriptor name of 22 characters). [] []<